# ValueError: Using a target size (torch.Size([2, 1])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([16, 1])) is deprecated

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to build a model for the Quora questions pair dataset where the output is binary either 1 or 0, but I get this error. I know the output shape of my model is different from the input shape, but I don't know how to fix it. The batch size is set to 16

```
    class Bert_model (nn.Module):
      def __init__(self) :
        super(Bert_model,self).__init__()
        self.bert =  BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', return_dict=False)
        self.drop_layer = nn.Dropout(.25)
        self.output = nn.Linear(self.bert.config.hidden_size,1)
    
      def forward(self,input_ids,attention_mask):
        _,o2 = self.bert (input_ids =input_ids , attention_mask = attention_mask )
        o2 = self.drop_layer(o2)
        return self.output(o2)

    model = Bert_model()
    
    loss_fn = nn.BCELoss().to(device)

    def train_epoch(
      model, 
      data_loader, 
      loss_fn, 
      optimizer, 
      device, 
      n_examples
    ):
      model = model.train()
    
      losses = []
      correct_predictions = 0
      
      for d in data_loader:
        input_ids = d["input_ids"].to(device)
        attention_mask = d["attention_mask"].to(device)
        targets = d["target"].to(device)
    
        input_ids = input_ids.view(BATCH_SIZE,-1)
        attention_mask = attention_mask.view(BATCH_SIZE,-1)
    
        outputs = model(
          input_ids=input_ids,
          attention_mask=attention_mask
        )
    
        _, preds = torch.max(outputs, dim=1)
    
        targets = targets.unsqueeze(-1)
        loss = loss_fn(F.softmax(outputs,dim=1), targets)
    
        correct_predictions += torch.sum(preds == targets)
        losses.append(loss.item())
    
        loss.backward()
        nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), max_norm=1.0)
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
    
      return correct_predictions.double() / n_examples, np.mean(losses)
```

The error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in
binary_cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, reduce,
reduction)    2913         weight = weight.expand(new_size)    2914 
-> 2915     return torch._C._nn.binary_cross_entropy(input, target, weight, reduction_enum)    2916     2917  ValueError: Using a target
size (torch.Size([2, 1])) that is different to the input size
(torch.Size([16, 1])) is deprecated
```

Comment: Can you add the stack trace of the error?

Comment: i added it in the post

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace, the error happens in the BCELoss computations, this is due to the fact that the `outputs.shape` is `(16, 1)`, while `targets.shape` is `(2, 1)`.

I see a major issue in your code: `BCELoss` is used to compare probability distributions (check the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCELoss.html)), but your model output has shape `(n, 1)` where `n` is the batch size (in your case 16).
In fact in the return statement of `forward` you pass `o2` to a linear layer whose output shape is `1`.

The [Question Pairs Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/quora/question-pairs-dataset) is meant for binary classification tasks, so you need to convert your output into a probability distribution, for example, by using a `Sigmoid` or setting the linear layer output size to 2, and then using the softmax.

Comment: In addition you can switch `BCELoss` with `CrossEntropyLoss`, which is meant for binary classification problems.

Comment: i change the loss function to (BCEWithLogitsLoss) which applies sigmoid to the output , then I removed the softmax . the problem still exists but now because target size is (10,1) and different from input (16,1)

Comment: It is difficult to tell the error from your code. Given that 16 is the correct batch size, carefully check when your target size changes from 16 to 10.

Please avoid changing the body of your question otherwise the answers will not make sense anymore.